# Update not Working in Hibernate many to Many Relational Table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to design a CRUD controller, in here Insert and Delete operation working perfectly but the update isn't working. When submitting for updating, only user table is updated but Role table isn't updated.

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 128, nullable = false)
    private String firstName; 

    @Column(length = 128, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;                       // required; unique

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length=128)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 128, nullable = false)
    private String password;                    // required

    @Column
    private boolean enabled;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "company_user",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "companyId")
    )
    private Set<Company> companies = new HashSet<Company>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName="id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roleId", referencedColumnName="id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
```

**Role.java**

```
@Entity
public class Role extends BaseObject {
    @Column(length = 64)
    private String description;
```

**UserController.java**

```
@PostMapping("/saveUser")
        public void save(@ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse rsp) throws IOException {

            user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()));
        //  LOGGER.info("--------------role User ID----------" + user.getRoles());
            user.setRoles(user.getRoles());
            userService.registerUser(user);

            req.setAttribute("users", userService.findAllUsers());
            req.setAttribute("mode", "USER_VIEW");
            rsp.sendRedirect("showUser");
        }


**UserService.Java**


public User registerUser(User user) {
        Optional<User> exists = userRepository.findOneByName(user.getName());
        return exists.isPresent() ? userRepository.save(exists.get().merge(user))
                : userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

How can I overcome this situation? Please help me.....

Comment: I don't really understand the line `user.setRoles(user.getRoles());`; it doesn't add nothing 'new' to the user entity

Answer (score 1):

Try to Use  **cascade = CascadeType.ALL**  on this field
    **private Set roles = new HashSet();**

I am assuming your isPresent is returning false and UserRepository.save(user) is running which will save only the Users not Roles as you are using **cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}**
It will potentially Solve your problem.